# Can I use a separate 24V transformer with an Ecobee 3 and an Aube relay?

Tags: electrical, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, transformer

I've purchased an Ecobee 3 Lite smart thermostat which requires 3.5 VA to operate but I'm using an [Aube RC840T-240](http://www.aubetech.com/products/produitsDetails.php?noLangue=2&noProduit=42) electric heating relay with 24 V transformer which only provides 1.2 VA.

Can I purchase a separate 120V (to connect to a different circuit or outlet) to 24 V transformer and use that to provide enough power for the thermostat?  If so, how would I wire my thermostat?  (The Aube relay/transformer provides R, W, and C wires so what would I connect from the Aube and from the external transformer?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### This is A-OK

Wire R and W from the relay box to Rh and W/W1 on the Ecobee, while leaving the relay's C terminal unused.  Then wire the secondary of the separate transformer to Rc and C on the Ecobee.  The Ecobee will figure all the rest out by itself, running off of the separate transformer on Rc while switching power from Rh to W to control the heat.

P.S. any standard 24VAC HVAC transformer will do here.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Can you explain why I need both R from the relay box and R from the new 24V transformer?  Aren't they both 24V sources?

Comment: They are going back to different places, and electricity needs to be sent back the way it came.